# is there any webkit source built in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webkit, chromium

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 as IDE.
I'd like to try to use webkit.net in my machine.
so I have been looked around all nights and download source.
when building in vs 2010, it occurs several errors.
I've found some instructions for that.
even following them, it doesn't work well.
what's wrong with me.
is there any vs2010 webkit project without changing any code?
thanks for your attention.

Comment: "Without changing any code." What else is there to do?

Comment: What errors occur? Are you downloading the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet)?